# Broken DS card?

Tags: nintendo-ds

I was playing Mario Kart DS in a bus terminal one day since I was on a long layover, and as I was loading a new map, it blanked out on me for several minutes. Confused, I turned my DS off then on, and upon turning it back on, the DS gives me the message "No DS card found".

It's not the DS, as my copy of SoulSilver works just fine. I tried a few remedies, but to no avail. I've attempted blowing it out, swabbing it... One other remedy I found suggested that the pins might not be touching, and to put a small piece of business card behind the DS card so it fits more snugly. That didn't work.

I don't understand why the card would suddenly brick like this. I wasn't moving around, the DS was being held in the air, nothing hit it or knocked out of place, it simply broke out of random.

Has anybody come across this problem? Is there a fix or something else I can try?

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: Does the card work in any other DSes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a new cartridge, it might be under warranty from Nintendo.

Comment: It's too old for warranty, I believe. I don't even have any of the original packaging or any receipts or anything of the sort.